# Why won't CAS accept "client_credential" in supportedGrantTypes field of service JSON definition?

Tags: oauth-2.0, configuration-files, cas

Per the [cas documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html), the service definition for an OAuth Client accepts a **supportedGrantTypes** field.  But when I add that field to my service definition, as such:

```
"supportedGrantTypes":["client_credentials"]
```

I receive this error at CAS startup time, and the service is not registered:

> Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService","clientId":"test_client","clientSecret":"clientSe...] to deserialize into type [interface org.apereo.cas.services.RegisteredService]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Could not resolve type id 'client_credentials' as a subtype of [collection type; class java.util.HashSet, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]: no such class found
>  at [Source: (String)"{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService","clientId":"test_client","clientSecret":"clientSecret","bypassApprovalPrompt":true,"generateRefreshToken":false,"serviceId":"test_client","name":"TestOAuthClient","id":"100","supportedGrantTypes":["client_credentials"]}"; line: 1, column: 291] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService["supportedGrantTypes"])]>
> 2018-07-26 21:22:16,196 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - 
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'client_credentials' as a subtype of [collection type; class java.util.HashSet, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]: no such class found
>  at [Source: (String)"{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService","clientId":"test_client","clientSecret":"clientSecret","bypassApprovalPrompt":true,"generateRefreshToken":false,"serviceId":"test_client","name":"TestOAuthClient","id":"100","supportedGrantTypes":["client_credentials"]}"; line: 1, column: 291] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService["supportedGrantTypes"])
>         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar!/:2.9.5]

The dependencies in my overlay project contain what I believe to be the require set of modules:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-oauth-webflow</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-json-service-registry</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Cany anybody tell me why CAS won't accept this supportedGrantTypes parameter?  FWIW, there is a workaround, which is to simply leave supportedGrantTypes out of the service definition altogether. But I'd like to understand what is actually going on here.

CAS version: 5.3.1

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

`{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService",
  "clientId": "clientid",
  "clientSecret": "clientSecret",
  "serviceId" : "^(https|imaps)://<redirect-uri>.*",
  "name" : "OAuthService",
  "id" : 100,
  "supportedGrantTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "...", "..." ] ],
  "supportedResponseTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "...", "..." ] ]
}`